# Declaring Variables as static: Unexpected behaviour

Tags: java, arraylist, static, spring-data

I am developing a `Java Spring` project that uses `Spring data`.

It uses `repositories` to remove Dog Objects from a Kennel Object when the dog is collected by its owner.

Note that there can be *multiple* dogs associated with the one Kennel. There are also many kennels.

I have declared all my variables and methods as `Static`.

E.g:

```
static Kennel kennel;

dogsWithReleasedStatus;

static List<Dog> dogsWithReleasedStatus = new ArrayList<Dog>();

static List<Dog> allDogsInKennel = new ArrayList<Dog>();
```

**Remove Method:**

```
public static void removeDogFromKennel(int dogInKennel, List<Dog> allDogsInKennel) {
        //Loop through all dogs in the Kennel
        for (dogInKennel = 0; dogInKennel < allDogsInKennel.size(); dogInKennel++) {

            if (allDogsInKennel.get(dogInKennel).getStatus() == dogStatus.RELEASED) {

                kennel.removeDog(allDogsInKennel.get(dogInKennel));

                dogInKennel--;


            }
        }
    }
```

**Calling remove method in the main:**

(note getAllKennelIds() just returns a list of kennel Ids as strings ):

```
List<String> kennelIdsToloopThrough = getAllKennelIds();

 for (int i = 0; i < kennelIdsToloopThrough.size(); i++) {

 //create list with all dogs in kennels 
 allDogsInKennel = kennel.getDogsList();

 //pass list and remove dog from kennel if status = released
 removeDogFromKennel(i,allDogsInKennel);

 //save the changes to the DB
 kennelRepository.save(kennel);

 }
```

The issue I am having is that when the *save* method is called, it is deleting **ALL** the dogs in kennels, not just those with a *"released"* status.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please post the `Dog` and the dogStatus code as well

Comment: What is in your `save()` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note that there can be multiple dogs associated with the one Kennel. There are also many kennels.

Currently there is *nothing* associated with an individual `Kennel`. The fact that all your variables are static means that they are associated with the `Kennel` *type* rather than with a specific *instance* of the type.

Fundamentally, you need to work out what information is specific to an individual kennel (such as the dogs within it) - and those fields should *not* be static.

You should read the ["Understanding Class Members"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) tutorial (or a good Java book) for more information about the difference between static fields and instance fields.

I would additionally *strongly* advise you to put away Spring, databases etc and just experiment with the basics of the language before you go any further.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. What I don't understand is why are all the Dogs being deleted from the kennel when the Save() method is called? I ask as you stated above that there is "nothing" associated with the Kennel, but there must be for the deletes to be carried out?

Comment: @java123999: I don't know what is going on behind the scenes there, but you should first focus on building a model that makes sense within Java. If you want a different list of dogs per kennel, then that list shouldn't be in a static variable. I would try to model this purely in memory first - write a little test harness allowing you to print the state of each kennel etc. Once you've got that working, I'd expect the DB integration to work a lot more easily.

Comment: Ok thanks, so essentially what may be happening is that when the save() method is called, is it being called on the static Kennel variable, so it is just saving all, rather than a specific Kennel?

Comment: @java123999: Well you said all of your variables are static, so there's nothing that is specific to one kennel anyway. (If you'd posted a [mcve] it would be easier to reason about what's going on...)